# Need help on the physics of angry-birds

Tags: matlab, physics

As a school project i have taken up making an angry birds clone in matlab. After working on it a little bit, i have realized that perhaps i bit more then i could chew.

Currently i am working on the physics of it, and while i understand the mechanics behind the game (collisions, inertia and whatnot) i don't know how i will implement it in the game. I am new to programming but i like it and have caught on to it fairly quickly.

In angry birds we are dealing with collisions between several OBB's and i have an algorithm for detecting collisions. I have a function that checks all the corners of every box and looks to see if it is within another box. I realize this is not the best way to do it but since i couldn't visualize the separating axis theorem, i chose not to use it.

When the collision happens, the box is penetrating into another box, when this happens i do a liner interpolation between its previous point and the current point. I do this to all colliding points in one instance (this is my method to resolve multiple collisions). Using the interpolation i detect the first collision that takes place and i implement a collision response.

My issue currently is that when there is one box sitting on top of another, this method doesnt work so well, because at every instance the top box penetrates into the bottom one very slightly, and i bounce it back. This causes my entire thing to stop, because i go back in time, solve the collision, and then in the next instance the collision is happening again.

My question is, how do i solve this problem of multiple boxes sitting on top of one another.

I have looked at all of the articles on physics by http://www.wildbunny.co.uk and tried to understand his method but while i understand what he does, i have no clue how he does it. I also do not know any action script so much of his code is gibberish to me.

I have looked through several other guides on the internet but none of them seem to make sense to me.

Here is what would be of great help to me, if someone could tell me what sort of method is commonly used to implement the graphics of a game like angry-birds, specifically the multiple collisions method (is mine good enough or do i need to do speculative contacts like wildbunny talks about in his blog), and the box resting on box problem.

Is this project difficult to do withing two weeks?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the physics engine used by Angry Birds? If so, it's Box 2D.

Comment: In two weeks, you might be better off implementing a much simpler version of the game - for example, with a single box on a fixed post.

Comment: No, i have to implement the physics myself.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Implementing a robust multiple body physics engine in matlab, from scratch, without experience working on physics engines and without programming experience is too difficult for a two week project.

Comment: I will work on getting this project changed, but for now could you tell me if my method would work?

Comment: @user1348051, consider posting a more specific version of this on [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)